# Find the twig file of the current view

Tags: symfony, twig

When I want to modify something in the current view I have  to see the action and the controller( `DefaultController:indexAction` for example ) , go to the action function ( `indexAction` ) and see what file that action is rendering.

Is there a faster way to find out which is the file (`xxxx.html.twig`) that is getting rendered in the current view ?

Comment: If you have access to the debug toolbar, you can see it in the Timeline section. If you don't want to click, you would probably have to use this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html

Comment: I will stick to the Timeline option for now, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your main layout, you can add something like this :

```
{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}
    {% block templateName %}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

And where you want to see your layout's path, you put :

```
{% block templateName %}{{ _self.templateName }}{% endBlock %}
```

This will display the template name everywhere you want when you're in development enviornment.